# export dynamic html table to excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, winforms, html-table

i am generating dynamic html table using web browser control . And now, im having problem to export it to excel. As im searching it thru internet, mostly said use syntax"Response.write" or "htmlcontext.current" but i cannot use those syntax due to I'm using Windows Form.

is there any other way to export it to excel? I really need help on this. Thanks!

Comment: Read [ask] and show relevant code. Yes, you can write HTML and call it Excel, this will usually just work. If you actually have a problem, then properly explain this problem. What problem are you having, what do you need help with? Writing a file?

Comment: okay im sorry for that. i actually coding html by using web browser control and i make it as string. then i convert this to web browser again. I succeed in exporting the html table to excel but it display as exactly on web browser as it supposed to have its header, column and data only. @CodeCaster

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools available to generate Excel documents from .Net, for example:

- [SpreadSheetLight](http://spreadsheetlight.com/license/)
- [NPOI](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi)
- [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus)
- [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML)

Comment: is there any way that we didnt use any 3rd party tool? @SBFrancies